# Java EE application deployment on Weblogic

Tags: java, deployment, jms, ejb-3.0, weblogic

I am looking to deploy & configure a Java EE application on weblogic with the following configuration
Machine -1 ,Mananged server -1 webbapplication i..e War deployment on managed server-1
2 issues 
Machine -2 ,Mananged server -2 EAR deployment, JDBC, JMS server(modules, resources, queue and queue connection factory targetted to only managed server -2)  Configuration on managed server-2
 no issues with managed server -2 deployment and configuration

the 2 issues with the managed-server-1 are
This setup isn’t working and having he following issues when I deploy the war
1.  <11-Apr-2011 15:26:03 o'clock BST>     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1302531963725>

1. weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160200]Error resolving ejb-ref 'gov.rpa.rita.rlr.soplot.request.jsf.MapPackRequestController/dataServiceFacade' from module 'MapPackProduction-war.war' of application 'MapPackProduction-war'. The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has not been specified. Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target bean failed because no EJBs in the application were found to implement the 'gov.rpa.rita.rlr.mappack.ejb.facade.DataServiceRemote' interface. Please link or map this ejb-ref to its target EJB and ensure the interfaces declared in the ejb-ref are correct.

Machine -2 ,Mananged server -2 EAR deployment, JDBC, JMS server(modules, resources, queue and queue connection factory targetted to only managed server -2)  Configuration on managed server-2
 no issues with managed server -2 deployment and configuration

if it is useful to answer more information on my approach is that I am not using weblogic clustering as this application is going to be deployed  without clustering as we dont have oracle licence for cluster.

Am I correct in my approach ? if yes please suggest resolution for 2 issues on managed server-1

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but the ejb-link error seems to indicate that you are trying to use an EJB from code in your WAR file.  My first guess is that you are trying to package an EJB in a WAR file.  This will not work with Java EE5.  You need to package the WAR containing your webapp and your EJB JAR file in an EAR.

If the EJB is deployed separately, and you are trying to use ejb-link to do EJB injection, take a look at the ejb-jar.xml configuration reference to make sure you have it set up correctly.  Also, look at the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml reference and see what you can do there.

Comment: thanks for your response jeff, sorry for the confusion,  I am trying to deploy war in one managed server and ejb in another managed server I want to access the ejb from war, how can i get hold of ejb that is deployed on a seperate managed server.

Comment: What is the purpose of deploying them separately?  I might suggest deploying them together in an EAR and using a WebLogic cluster.  That way you can utilize the horsepower in both machines.  If your concern is about CPU allocation, you can use Work Managers to address that...

Comment: thanks again Jeff, the licence of Weblogic that we have got doesnt have clustering feature and the client doesn't want to spend any more. however i have sorted the issue by creating 2 Ears with diff application code combined with the library which gets deployed on both managed servers which has solved the problem. Cheers for your responses.